# How to send a blank accept header with Curl - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I've seen a couple of related issues, but unfortunately, none of the recommended solutions had solved my problem.

I'm trying to send in a blank Accept header using PHP curl:

PHP Version: 7.3
Disto: Debian

```php
    /**
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $body
     * @param array $headers
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function execute(string $method, string $url, string $body = '', array $headers = []): Response
    {
        $curlHeaders = [];
        $isAcceptHeaderPresent = false;
        $isExpectHeaderPresent = false;
        $curl = \curl_init();
        $response = new Response();
        foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
            $curlHeaders[] = $value === '' ? "{$name};" : "{$name}: $value";

            $name = \strtolower($name);
            if ($name === 'accept') {
                $isAcceptHeaderPresent = true;
            }

            if ($name === 'expect') {
                $isAcceptHeaderPresent = true;
            }
        }

        if ($isAcceptHeaderPresent === false) {
            $curlHeaders[] = 'Accept: ';
        }

        if ($isExpectHeaderPresent === false) {
            $curlHeaders[] = 'Expect: ';
        }

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => \str_replace(' ', '%20', $url),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => [$response, 'headerWrite'],
            CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => [$response, 'bodyWrite'],
            CURLOPT_FILE => $response->getBodyAsResouce(),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curlHeaders,
        ];

        switch ($method) {
            case 'GET':
            case 'POST':
            case 'PATCH':
            case 'PUT':
            case 'HEAD':
            case 'DELETE':
            case 'CONNECT':
            case 'OPTIONS':
            case 'TRACE':
                $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = $method;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Unsupported HTTP method received: ' . $method);
        }

        \curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        \curl_exec($curl);
        $response->setStatusCode(\curl_getinfo($curl)['http_code']);
        \curl_close($curl);

        return $response;
    }
```

If `Accept:` is provided, then no Accept header will be sent in what so ever.

Whereas `Accept;` make it so, that the blank value will be sent in along with `*/*` value as well: `"accept":"*/*,`

Is there a way to send in just the `Accept:` header as is?

I wonder if this mechanism has been changed in the last couple of PHP and curl extension releases, given that none of the suggestions are working as intended.

Comment: Okay, I just tested this using different Docker images, default images are Debian based, and they behave the same way as I've described in my post.
(I've tested 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0, and 5.6)

Alpine based images are fine, and they are sending the blank accept header as expected.

So this is environmental and only occurs in Debian based platforms.

Comment: For future reference I've created the following github issue: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see description of the issue in github.com/docker-library/php/issues/832

Tldr; debian uses ancient 2.5y old curl package while other platforms are using newer versions. There must be a bug that's causing this.

If you are on debian, and if you want to send a blank accept header using curl, you'll have to update the version to 7.64.0 from the (testing) repo.